# Select Result grouped by all fields

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select

I want result grouped by all of the fields. I achieved it by the use of - **WITH** keyword.
Is there any other way to do that?

```
WITH    T AS ( SELECT   a.codeid AS VendorID ,
                                    a.hname ,
                                    a.hnamee ,
                                    CASE WHEN v.AudienceID = 0 THEN 1
                                         ELSE 0
                                    END AS HasAll
                           FROM     dbo.dtAny AS a
                                    LEFT JOIN VendorAudience AS v ON a.codeid = v.VendorID
                           WHERE    a.hrclvl = @level
                                    AND a.dcode = @dcode
                                    AND a.codeid = ISNULL(@VendorID, a.codeid)
                         )
    SELECT  VendorID ,
            hname ,
            hnamee ,
            HasAll
    FROM    T
    GROUP BY vendorid ,
            hname ,
            hnamee ,
            HasAll
```

I want something like this:

```
  SELECT   a.codeid AS VendorID ,
                                    a.hname ,
                                    a.hnamee ,
                                    CASE WHEN v.AudienceID = 0 THEN 1
                                         ELSE 0
                                    END AS HasAll
                           FROM     dbo.dtAny AS a
                                    LEFT JOIN VendorAudience AS v ON a.codeid = v.VendorID
                           WHERE    a.hrclvl = @level
                                    AND a.dcode = @dcode
                                    AND a.codeid = ISNULL(@VendorID, a.codeid)
                                    GROUP BY VendorID ,a.hname ,a.hnamee ,HasAll
```

but there is error trying to group by HasAll.(I don't need to group by v.AudienceID)

Comment: Why don't you use `distinct` instead of grouping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query should be

```
SELECT   a.codeid AS VendorID ,
                                    a.hname ,
                                    a.hnamee ,
                                    CASE WHEN v.AudienceID = 0 THEN 1
                                         ELSE 0
                                    END AS HasAll
                           FROM     dbo.dtAny AS a
                                    LEFT JOIN VendorAudience AS v ON a.codeid = v.VendorID
                           WHERE    a.hrclvl = @level
                                    AND a.dcode = @dcode
                                    AND a.codeid = ISNULL(@VendorID, a.codeid)
                                    GROUP BY VendorID ,a.hname ,a.hnamee ,
                                    CASE WHEN   v.AudienceID = 0 THEN 1
                                         ELSE 0
                                    END
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use it as a derived table.

```
SELECT VendorID ,a.hname ,a.hnamee ,HasAll
FROM (SELECT a.codeid AS VendorID ,
        a.hname ,
        a.hnamee ,
        CASE WHEN v.AudienceID = 0 THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END AS HasAll
    FROM     dbo.dtAny AS a
        LEFT JOIN VendorAudience AS v ON a.codeid = v.VendorID
    WHERE    a.hrclvl = @level
        AND a.dcode = @dcode
        AND a.codeid = ISNULL(@VendorID, a.codeid)) [Table]
GROUP BY VendorID ,a.hname ,a.hnamee ,HasAll
```

Comment: And does this differ from using of "WITH"?

Answer (score 0):

That's what `DISTINCT` is used for:

```
WITH    T AS ( SELECT   a.codeid AS VendorID ,
                        a.hname ,
                        a.hnamee ,
                        CASE WHEN v.AudienceID = 0 THEN 1
                             ELSE 0
                        END AS HasAll
               FROM     dbo.dtAny AS a
                        LEFT JOIN VendorAudience AS v ON a.codeid = v.VendorID
               WHERE    a.hrclvl = @level
                        AND a.dcode = @dcode
                        AND a.codeid = ISNULL(@VendorID, a.codeid)
             )
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM T
```

Answer (score 0):

Using DISTINCT is unnecessary if you are grouping by ALL the columns because the output will be unique anyway. I tend to agree with Miika above but there is not reason your original approach will not work.

Mac